# Appending in JQuery

Tags: jquery

i am having a HTML like

```
<p style="" class="fieldChoices title">Choices:
   <input value="option1" maxlength="150" id="Choice1"/>
   <div class="seperator"/>
   <p class="deleteChoice1 cutsom_button">
   <a class="btn lbOn deletechoice" href="#">
   <span class="button_image"><span class="background_16 user_reply">Delete</span>        
   </span>
   </a></p>
   <div class="seperator"/>
   <input value="option2" maxlength="150" id="Choice2"/>
   <div class="seperator"/>
   <p class="deleteChoice2 cutsom_button">
       <a class="btn lbOn deletechoice" href="#">
       <span class="button_image">
       <span class="background_16 user_reply">Delete</span>
      </span>
      </a></p>
  <div class="seperator"/>
  <p class="addChoice cutsom_button">
  <a class="btn lbOn addchoice" href="#">
  <span class="button_image">
  <span class="background_16 user_reply">Add</span>
 </span>
 </a>
 </p>
</p>
```

on CLicking of this add i am adding choices like using JQUery
as

```
  $(".addChoice").live("click", function(){

                //alert($(".fieldChoices input").length);
                var length=$(".fieldChoices input").length;
                length++;

                $("<input id='Choice"+length+"' maxlength='150' value=option"+length+">").appendTo(".fieldChoices");

                $("<div class='seperator'/>").appendTo(".fieldChoices");    

                $("<p class='deleteChoice"+length+" cutsom_button'><a href='#' class='btn lbOn deletechoice'><span class='button_image'><span class='background_16 user_reply'>Delete</span></span></a></p>").appendTo(".fieldChoices");
                            $("<div class='seperator'/>").appendTo(".fieldChoices");

                return false;
            });
```

when i did this it genrates the input element with the option3 ,...
But all these are appending to the end of the .fieldChoices..
But i am trying to make this appear in this .fieldChoices but before Add

tag ..

How to append so in JQuery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain it together as a single string and use jQuery's [before](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/before) method to insert the HTML before the `.addChoice` element:

```
 $('.addChoice').live('click', function(){
 var length=$('.fieldChoices input').length + 1;
 $(this).before(
  '<input id="Choice' + length + '" maxlength="150" value="option' + length + '" />' +
  '<div class="seperator" />' +
  '<p class="deleteChoice' + length + ' cutsom_button"><a href="#" class="btn lbOn deletechoice"><span class="button_image"><span class="background_16 user_reply">Delete</span></span></a></p>' +
  '<div class="seperator" />'
 );
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`appendTo()` adds things to the end of that element.

I think you want `prependTo()`.

Comment: but that would make things appear in the wrong order in his case, since he's doing 4 appends for each click. Using prependTo would be a better option, though, if all the html was put together in one string first, then prepended. (Which actually is the best way to do it anyway (fewer DOM-interactions))

Comment: It would put them in the wrong order even if they are called all at once in a selector?

Comment: Nope, only if they are called one after another. Because the second would be put in before the first, and the third would be put in before the second and so on. But chaining them would fix the problem.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. If they click add more than once it would go at the top of the first one...

I would personally have it start off with a default option and then have it go After() the last option in the element (or appendTo the element if they were at the very bottom).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery `before()` method

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/before#content

Comment: I think the difference between our ideas is prependTo would add the new element *inside* the target element, so if he started with `  <p class="addChoice cutsom_button"><a></a></p>">` and used prependTo("<p>blah</p>'), he'd end up with : `<p class="addChoice cutsom_button"><p>blah</p><a></a></p>` but with before, he'd get: `<p>blah</p><p class="addChoice cutsom_button"><a></a></p>`